# Eclipse PDT and Hg (Mercurial)

Tags: eclipse, version-control, mercurial

We'd like to switch up from SVN to Git or Mercurial at work, and Mercurial we would like to investigate first.

I have installed Hg on my Windows machine and got the Eclipse plugin, but I don't get a perspective like I do for SVN inside of Eclipse PDT.

Does this not exist, or do I have the wrong flavor of Eclipse? I would like to see my repos in one window while I code in the other like I do with SVN.

Also, do the commands appear in the context menu (right click) under Team? So far, I can't see that Mercurial is in my Eclipse PDT environment other than when I want to Import a project, I have a few Hg options.

Any Hg/Eclipse pros know if this is by-design or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can follow this "[DVCS part 3: team… options and first steps using EGit, HgEclipse](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/2010/02/17/dvcs-part-3-team%E2%80%A6-options-and-first-steps-using-egit-hgeclipse/)" tutorial, from the **[Ekke's DVCS pages](http://ekkescorner.wordpress.com/blog-series/git-mercurial/)**.
In this latter page, you will find many comment on HgEclipse views and menus.

**EGit – and HgEclipse Views or Perspectives ?**

> If I’m exploring new things I always take a look if there are special Perspectives or Views provided.
>   In case of  aVCS – Team Provider Plug-in from my experiences using CVS I expected that there would also be a Perspective for Git or Mercurial repositories.
>   **But both Plug-ins don’t provide an own perspective.**
>
> Next step I take a look at the Views and **found that `HgEclipse` provides some extra Views**:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Most Mercurial tasks are performed using the context menu or via custom keyboard shortcuts (Preferences → General → Keys → type `Mercurial` in the search box)

MercurialEclipse also works nicely with the *Team Synchronising* perspective; especially for pushing/pulling to a remote server.